# how to get data from two different collections using ng-repeat

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have two collections one for users and other for posts and i am trying to get username like who posted the feed on the page. curretnly i am getting something like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yesvp.png)

and want to implement something like twitter. but as the user data and posts is in two different collections. i can only get "_id" on the post. the following are the files

Models/story.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var StorySchema = new Schema({

creator: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
content: String,
create: { type:Date, default: Date.now }
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
```

Models/user.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    username: { type:String, required: true, index: { unique: true}},
    password: { type: String, reuired: true, select: false }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
        if(err) return next(err);

        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });

});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
    var user = this;
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

controllers/Storyctrl.js

```
angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])

.controller('StoryController', function(Story, socketio){

    vm = this;

    vm.stories=[];



    vm.getStories = function(){
        Story.all()

        .success(function(data){
            vm.stories = data;
        });
    };

    vm.createStory = function(){

        vm.message = '';

        Story.create(vm.storyData)
            .success(function(data){
                vm.storyData.content = '';
                vm.message = data.message;

                // vm.getStories(); // Refresh

                // vm.stories.push(vm.storyData);
            });

    };

    vm.getStories();

    socketio.on('story', function(data){
        vm.stories.push(data);
    });
})

.controller('allStoriesController', function(stories, socketio){

    var vm = this;

    vm.stories = stories.data;


    socketio.on('story', function(data){
        vm.stories.push(data);
    });

})
```

the Html file

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Stories</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group" >




                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="s in story.stories | reverse">

                            {{ s.content | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y" }}


                            <small>Posted by @  {{s.creator}}</small>
                             <small class="pull-right">{{s.create | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}</small>



                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>

</div>
```

i am new to nodejs and mongodb please spare me in comments if there is a minor mistake or something that i have not covered yet.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs you have to use **population** of the objects with reference.
it's a ORM feature not the mongodb native feature so while using **mongoose ORM** you have to populate your object with the reference id and the populated object replaces the json variable as object after query completion.
for detail you go to this link:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

here is the code which you have to write in the nodejs route file

**TestPopulation.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./connection');

// require mongoose models
var Story = mongoose.model('Story');
var Person = mongoose.model('Person');
  Person.find().populate({
    path: 'stories',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: '_creator' }
  }).exec(function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**connection.js**

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var personSchema = new Schema({
      _id     : Number,
      name    : String,
      age     : Number,
      stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
    });

    var storySchema = new Schema({
      _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
      title    : String,
      fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
    });

    mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
    mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

//mongoose runs only on 27017 port 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/spicex');
```

**output**

```
[{
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "Aaron",
    "age": 100,
    "__v": 0,
    "stories": [{
        "_id": "584d083038c162c81a69a013",
        "title": "Once upon a timex.",
        "_creator": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "Aaron",
            "age": 100,
            "__v": 0,
            "stories": ["584d083038c162c81a69a013"]
        },
        "__v": 0,
        "fans": []
        }]
    }, {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "sanjeev",
    "age": 100,
    "__v": 0,
    "stories": []
    }]
```